# Can sed edit a file in-place using w (write) command instead of -i flag, which is not specified in POSIX?

Tags: sed

`w` command of my `sed` (sed of macOS 13.1) seems to be able to edit the input file with `cat` (bash 3.2):

```
printf "hello\nworld\n" > foo.txt

cat foo.txt | sed 's/l/L/g' | sed -n 'w foo.txt'

cat foo.txt
> heLLo
> worLd
```

I looked over https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html but I'm not sure why the above pipeline can successfully edit `foo.txt`, unlike when using redirection such as `cat foo.txt | sed 's/l/L/g' > foo.txt`.

I know that I can use POSIX-nonspecified `-i` flag or temporary files, but I'm wondering if it is safe to use `w` (write) command to edit input files.

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
printf "%d hello world\n" {1..100000} > foo.txt

cat foo.txt | sed 's/l/L/g' | sed -n 'w foo.txt'
```

and found that it is no longer working properly. The resulting `foo.txt` has only 4000-8000 lines.

Comment: Does it still work with a much longer file? Try `printf "%d hello world\n" {1..100000} > foo.txt`, run your `sed` commands, and then `tail foo.txt` to check that the last line starts with 100000.

Comment: Since you are, in effect, using a pipe as temporary storage for a line of text, I expect this to break as soon as you get input with lines longer than the pipe buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sponge` (from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), **OR** redirect to a temporary file and rename it over the original, **OR** use [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/) (or `ex` from vi/vim/nvi) instead of `sed` - remember that `sed` is the stream-oriented version of `ed`.  `ed` = `editor`, `sed` = **stream** editor.

FYI: ed, sed, and ex (and vi too - vi started out as the **vi**sual version of ed) all share a common subset of commands as they all share common roots....but each of them has been developed in different directions and had different enhancements.  and each has multiple different versions, again with different capabilities.  Many other programs have borrowed at least some of those common commands (e.g. rogue and nethack both borrowed the hjkl movement keys). Also worth noting, in case it's not obvious: `ex` commands are the `:` commands inside vi, and are a superset of `ed` commands (depending on which implementation of `vi` you're using).

Examples of all three methods.

```
sed -e 's/l/L/g' foo.txt | sponge foo.txt

sed -e 's/l/L/g' foo.txt > foo.new && mv foo.new foo.txt

printf '%s\n' %s/l/L/g w q | ed -s foo.txt
printf '%s\n' %s/l/L/g w q | ex foo.txt
```

BTW, from `man sponge`:

> `sponge` reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
> Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing
> the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
> write to the same file.
>
> sponge preserves the permissions of the output file if it already exists.

Notes:

1. sponge is essentially a convenience tool for the redirect-and-rename method.
2. Redirect-and-rename does not preserve the permissions of the original output file.  It creates a new file with permissions determined by the user's `umask` (as with any other new file being created) - depending on the umask, these perms may or may not be the same as the original.

   The difference is that `sponge` **ensures** that the new file has the same perms as the original, while a simple redirection does not.
3. With both `ed` and `ex`, each command (the `s///` substitution, `w` for write and finally `q` for quit) is printed one per line with `printf '%s\n'` and piped into `ed` or `ex`, which open foo.txt and execute the commands.

---

Also note: `ed` and `ex` both overwrite the original file (retaining the original file's inode number and therefore NOT breaking any hard links of that file).   `sponge` and write-to-a-tempfile-and-rename both create new files with different inode numbers, which will break any hard links.  Most of the time (i.e. unless you have one or more hard links of the file), this will not matter at all but it is something you need to be aware of.

For example: note how the inode number changes with `sponge`:

```
$ printf "hello\nworld\n" > foo.txt
$ ls -li foo.txt
2251637 -rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 12 Feb  6 18:07 foo.txt
$ sed -e 's/l/L/g' foo.txt | sponge foo.txt
$ ls -li foo.txt
2251985 -rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 12 Feb  6 18:07 foo.txt
```

overwriting the file with redirection again doesn't change the inode number, and neither does editing it with ex (or ed):

```
$ printf "hello\nworld\n" > foo.txt
$ ls -li foo.txt
2251985 -rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 12 Feb  6 18:08 foo.txt
$ printf '%s\n' %s/l/L/g w q | ex foo.txt 
$ ls -li foo.txt
2251985 -rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 12 Feb  6 18:09 foo.txt
```

You can keep the original inode if it's needed with the redirect-and-rename method with something like:

```
sed -e 's/l/L/g' foo.txt > foo.new
cat foo.new > foo.txt
rm foo.new
```

Yes, i know `cat` isn't needed. `<` redirection works too.  I find that (redirection at the start of a command line, or redirection without an actual command) to be distastefully ugly and have no fear or shame of [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

And, as Stephen Kitt points out in a comment, `cp foo.new foo.txt` works too and also preserves the original permissions.

Comment: `cp foo.new foo.txt` works too (preserving the inode).

Comment: That's not a UUOC here, you still need a command to read foo.new and write the foo,txt. In zsh, you can do `<foo.new >foo.txt` but that still runs `cat` behind the scene as the `$NULLCMD`. You could do `<foo.new cat >foo.txt` if you didn't find it ugly. That would have the advantage of not overwriting `foo.txt` if `foo.new` could not be opened.

Answer (score 2):

The `w` `sed` command, upon first invocation (here upon `sed` processing its first line, after reading a block of data from the pipe) opens the output file with `O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC`, so at that point the file is emptied (*trunc*ated), so if the command that is reading the file (in your case `cat` has not finished reading it yet), it won't be able to read the rest.

Instead, you could do:

```
sed 's/l/L/g' < file 1<> file
```

Where the shell opens the file on sed's stdin with `O_RDONLY` and, independently, on sed's stdout with `O_RDWR`, but more importantly without `O_TRUNC` so `sed` will overwrite its own input.

That only works though if `sed` like here always writes lines of output that are the exact same size (in number of bytes) as the lines it read, as otherwise it could end up overwriting lines that it hasn't read yet.

If what it writes is shorter than what it reads, it would also leave old data at the end of the file. That could be addressed by calling something that truncates stdout in place at the end like:

```
{ sed 's/hello/hi/g'; perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'; } < file 1<> file
```

But if you're going to use `perl`, you might as well use its `-i` that some `sed` implementations have copied:

```
perl -pi -e 's/hello/hi/g' file
```